# Export Regression Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, stargazer

How do you export the Stargazer Python regression output to a HTML file, PDF or png, after doing:

`stargazer.render_latex()`
or

`stargazer.render_html()`

https://github.com/mwburke/stargazer/blob/9ee4c40bee45a689b209ea7b21b2bcbc3d036356/README.md#latex-example

Comment: Did you find an answer already?